# Can an HTML button element inherit it's value from parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible for a button to inherit its' value property from its' parent element?

I have 3 buttons in an li and I want to retrieve a value common to all buttons in the li as well as the specific button pressed (which I could accomplish with unique ids). Open to any form of restructuring so that I can achieve this easily.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Below is an example of what I'm working on, the value of the li is the value I want to retrieve for all three buttons as well as some defining detail of which action was taken.

```
side += "<li href='#' class='list-group-item' value="+friend.id+" style='height:75px'>";
side += "<button type='button' onclick='sidebarUserOptions(this)' style='height:95%; width:15%;'>View</button>";
side += "<button type='button' onclick='sidebarUserOptions(this)' style='height:95%; width:15%;'>Visit</button>";
side += "<button type='button' onclick='sidebarUserOptions(this)'style='height:95%; width:15%;'>Edit</button>";
side += "</li>";
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is is you need and show us what you've tried?

Comment: What's your ("[mcve]") HTML? And have you tried to solve this problem yourself? What specific result, or output, do you want given the HTML that you'll be posting? Should this be in response to a user-action, or event?

Comment: Some code to give context would help. All in all, it looks like you can do `onclick` on each button that calls a function with `(this)`, never mind, you don't even need `(this)` because it is already present in the `onclick` event. Then you can edit your form and data you're sending over to the server to your heart's desire. For example, I have a bunch of buttons that change the form's action to the one that's stored inside the button's properties through `$(this).closest("form").attr("action",$(this).attr("formAction"));`

Comment: Pete Talks Web's solution is the easiest. I was being silly and just not approaching my DOM like the wonderful tree it is.

Answer (score 4):

In your onclick (sidebarUserOptions) you could refer to the this variable, get the parent node, and then get the value from that parent Node.

So, using jQuery:

```
$(this).parent().attr('value');
```

[Here is a working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/WrKxBm)

Comment: This is the one! Thanks! I was so busy thinking about how to "inherit" I didn't explore easy ways to just retrieve the parent.

Comment: Awesome! If you don't want to use jQuery, you can utilize the [parentNode property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) and [getAttribute() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) of vanilla HTML and JS

Answer (score 1):

No restructuring necessary. The key is to detect the click event on the `li` instead of the `button`. You can use `event.target`in the click function to get access to the button that was clicked. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lexicalnoscope/1dacLb7c/) demoing the concept. The first function `doToAll` is simply a helper method for iterating over a set of dom elements, and the output div is in place for an easy way of showing the result of the function.

HTML:

```
    <div id="output"></div>
<ul>
<li data-info="first li">
  <button>
  One
  </button>
  <button>
  Two
  </button>
  <button>
  Three
  </button>
</li>
<li data-info="second li">
  <button>
  One
  </button>
  <button>
  Two
  </button>
  <button>
  Three
  </button>
</li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function doToAll(elems, callback){
  var len = elems.length;
  while(--len > -1){
    callback(elems[len]);
  }
}

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  output = document.getElementById('output');

doToAll(lis, function(li){
  li.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var tgt = e.target, //get the element that was clicked on
      liparent = this; //the click event is bound to the li, so 'this' still refers to the list item and not the button
    if(tgt.tagName == "BUTTON"){//check to make sure a button was clicked, and not something else inside the li
      output.textContent = tgt.textContent + ', ' + liparent.getAttribute('data-info');
       //reports a piece of data from the button and the li
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically  yes, with [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) and [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```css
#parent {
  --value: attr(data-value);
}
#parent > button::after {
  content: var(--value);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" data-value="Hello!">
  <button type="button"></button>
  <button type="button"></button>
</div>
```

However, note that:

- No major implementation supports `attr` on properties different than `content`.
- CSS variables are currently only supported by Firefox and Safari.
- CSS pseudo-elements should only be used for decorative purposes, not to insert content.

Comment: I think saying that "it's not widely supported yet" is putting it rather mildly. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), it's not supported at all except in Firefox and Safari, which leaves out the majority of users.

Comment: This sets the content, so the user will see the generated button label. But it doesn't set the value, so it won't be submitted in the form.